# Strapi Error : 'TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be of type string'

Tags: node.js, strapi

I run command `npm run start` in Strapi project. Then I got an error:

> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be of type
> string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an
> Array-like Object. Received undefined

[Here my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwFse.png)

node version: v.16.16.0
npm version: 8.11.0
strapi version: 4.4.7

Comment: Could you please show contents of `config/server.js`?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I found answer my Strapi need the real env file.

Answer (score 0):

Although the answer is already present in @LaterGator's comment, sharing it here with a more detailed explaination for anyone who stumbles upon this issue in future:

In order to use the `strapi export` command, Strapi expects you to have `.env` file available in the root folder, for any environment variables that you might be using for your STRAPI CMS.

Comment: well I have that `.env` but still that error persists